# Background color on TTK combobox on MacOS

Tags: python, tkinter

So i have this weird grey-ish background color around my comboboxes on MacOS.

While using Tk i can solve this with setting highlightthickness to 0 but apparently it doesn't work with TTK.
Does anyone have a work around for that?
Thank you!

[image: Annoying Background]

Comment: You can use custom style for that.

Comment: @Sujay
Do you mean using the style function and configure it? 
I tried using it but i can't get it to work 
Do you have an example of a working code?

Comment: Can you post the code? What theme are you using?

Comment: One question: are you using frames?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. There are [some preset themes](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes) from ttk that creates consistent appearance regardless of your platform. They are alt, classic, clam, default. Use `ttk.Style().theme_use("theme_name")` to set the theme.